# django-disqus integration

Tags: django, disqus

1. I installed django-disqus on my site villaint.ru

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'disqus',
    )

   DISQUS_API_KEY = 'my_secret_api_key'
    DISQUS_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME = 'villaint'
2. In template:

   {% load disqus_tags %}
   {% disqus_show_comments %}

I am getting an error on page http://villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/:

```
Could not connect to URL: "http://villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/" (error was "[Errno -2] Name or service not known")
```

On page http://www.villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/ I have the following error:

```
Could not connect to URL: "http://www.villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/" (error was "HTTP Error 404: Not Found")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is not directly answering your question on django-disqus but if your only goal is to show the disqus comments in your posts, it's quite easy to do it directly.

In your template, just put:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'your_disqus_shortname'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    // The following are highly recommended additional parameters. Remove the slashes in front to use.
    // var disqus_identifier = 'unique_dynamic_id_1234';
    // var disqus_url = 'http://example.com/permalink-to-page.html';

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

Comment: It does not work, error: Could not connect to URL: "http://villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/" (error was "[Errno -2] Name or service not known")

Comment: @TigorC - Did you replace the `disqus_shortname` with yours? Are you sure that your domain `www.villaint.ru` is registered in your disqus account?

Comment: > Did you replace the disqus_shortname with yours?
yes.
Screenshot my disqus accaunt settings: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/978152-514201254049PM

Comment: It looks like your settings are correct. When I visit `http://www.villaint.ru/blog/entry/2/`, it immediately shows 404 Not Found error. I don't think this is a problem with disqus. Can you generate that page correctly without the disqus script?